# SQL Query: For each department that has one or more majors with a GPA under 1.0, print the name of the department and the average GPA of its majors

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

New to mySQL. Finishing up a project just have 2 queries left to write but I'm pretty much stuck on them.

Tables:

- -student(sid, sname, sex, age, year, gpa)
- -dept(dname, numphds)
- -prof(pname, dname)
- -course(cno, cname, dname)
- -major(dname, sid)
- -section(dname, cno, sectno, pname)
- -enroll(sid, grade, dname, cno, sectno)

***Queries needed:***

**1. For each department that has one or more majors with a GPA under
    1.0, print the name of the department and the average GPA of its majors.**

**2. Print the ids, names, and GPAs of the students who are currently taking all of the Civil Engineering courses.**

Heres some sample data from the database:

```
student
sid     sname           sex     age     year    gpa
1       Jacobs, T.      m       29      5       3.60
2       Pierson, E.     m       32      5       3.50
3       Zeene, Ben N.   m       21      5       3.90

dept
dname                   numphds
Chemical Engineering    32
Civil Engineering       88
Computer Sciences       47

prof
pname        dname
Brian, C.    Computer Sciences
Brown, S.    Civil Engineering
Bucket, T.   Sanitary Engineering

course
cno          cname                  dname
302          Intro to Programming   Computer Sciences
310          Thermodynamics         Chemical Engineering
310          Intro to Garbage       Sanitary Engineering

major
dname                   sid
Chemical Engineering    25
Chemical Engineering    26
Chemical Engineering    27

section
dname                   cno     sectno  pname
Chemical Engineering    310     1       Edison, L.
Civil Engineering       365     1       Randolph, B.
Civil Engineering       375     1       Brown, S.

enroll
sid     grade   dname                   cno     sectno
1       3.00    Chemical Engineering    310     1
2       3.00    Computer Sciences       302     1
3       3.50    Civil Engineering       375     1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Heres what I have for QUESTION 1:

```
select d.dname, AVG(s.gpa) from dept d, student s, major m 
                 where s.sid = m.sid and d.dname = m.dname 
                 and s.gpa <1 group by dname;
```

This works but doesnt give me the correct gpa for the dept, only the gpa of that specific student??

Comment: you could try asking your teacher, since i assume this is a homework question?

Comment: This is a homework project, of which I've completed the other 10 questions and seeking help for the remaining 2. If you aren't answering or providing help maybe you should just not say anything.

Comment: from the FAQ: `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`. Not just 'answer these questions for me'.  Also, the sample data you've given would result in no answers for the questions - maybe create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to encourage some help.

Comment: I dont want anyone to just come and solve it. I would rather someone give me an example of how to correctly write a query of this type. I never said "answer these questions for me", I said "any help would be appreciated". As for the sample data, the actual given database is huge so I wont post it for obvious reasons, that being said knowing the information posted for the tables is more then enough to solve this.

Comment: you have flagged this as mysql are mysql specific extensions allowed?

Comment: also, your queries are sufficiently trivial that the most basic example IS to just solve it - if you had posted what you had tried, you could have received explanations as to why what you tried didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 2:

```
   select s.sid, s.sname, s.gpa
      from student s
        inner join enroll e
          on s.sid = e.sid
      where e.dname = 'Civil Engineering'
      group by sid
      having count(distinct cno) = 
        (select count(cno) from course where dname = 'Civil Engineering');
```

Example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/807bc/1

We join student to enroll tables to get a list of all courses the students are enrolled in, we filter it to only courses that are in the Civil Engineering department, we then group them by student, and count the number of distinct courses the student is enrolled in (since in real life, a student may end up enrolling in the same course multiple times, over time), and compare that to total number of courses in the Civil Engineering department, and include only the result rows that match that last condition.

Question 1:

```
select d.dname, avg(s.gpa)
  from dept d
    inner join major m
      on d.dname = m.dname
    inner join student s
      on s.sid = m.sid
  group by d.dname
  having min(s.gpa) < 1.0
```

or

```
  select m.dname, avg(s.gpa)
    from major m
      inner join student s
        on s.sid = m.sid
  group by m.dname
  having min(s.gpa) < 1.0
```

Updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d12f4/5

The answer is constructed in a similar fashion. I've given two answers for the second because it seems weird to me that the department table doesn't have a department_id field that the other tables use, whereas instinct would suggest that it would.

Comment: Looks correct. I was breaking my head because of my incorrect use of having. Thanks.

Comment: and thats why it would have been nice to add your attempts to your question. anyway. good luck.

Comment: I added my attempt for Q1 now. I erased attempt for Q2 out of frustration...

Comment: where filters the rows before the grouping - having is for filtering after grouping

Comment: How would you fix my attempt? It shows the correct depts but only the gpa of the one individual student with a gpa<1 rather then the dept avg: select d.dname, AVG(s.gpa) from dept d, student s, major m where s.sid = m.sid and d.dname = m.dname and s.gpa <1 group by dname;

Comment: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d12f4/6). i added your query to the end and modified it to work. All you needed to do is remove the the gpa from the where clause, group by department (because you're looking at all the students per department), and then add the the gpa check to the having clause. but since having works on aggregates, you just check the min gpa, rather than the field directly

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. +++. I actually removed dept d all together I felt it was redundant since we can just use m.dname to get the d name and got the same result

Comment: yes. i'd call that a poor design choice - pass that back to your teacher heh

Comment: so heres the final updated one: select m.dname, AVG(s.gpa) from student s, major m where s.sid = m.sid group by m.dname having min(s.gpa) < 1.0;

Answer (score 0):

> 1. For each department that has one or more majors with a GPA under 1.0, print the name of the department and the average GPA of its majors.

Its pseudo piece of code. Try it if it works otherwise revert back with problem.

```
SELECT D.DNAME,AVG(S.GPA) FROM DEPT D, STUDENT S,MAJOR M
WHERE D.DNAME = M.DNAME AND M.SID = S.SID
GROUP BY DNAME HAVING MIN(S.GPA) < 1
```